# Turn off button highlighting in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui

how can i turn off the button highlighting in SwiftUI, when its tapped or pressed.

Here's my code:

```
ScrollView {
        ForEach(searchManager.resultUsers) { user in
            Button(action: {
                self.showProfile = true
                self.user = user
            }) {
                SearchUserRow(user: user)
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
            }
        }
    }.sheet(isPresented: $showProfile) {
        ProfileView(profileUser: self.user)
            .environmentObject(ProfileManager(userID: self.user.userID, fetchingMode: .user(mode: .tweets)))
    }
```

if i remove the button and add `onTapGesture` to `SearchUserRow` not the complete row is selectable, only the content part.

Comment: Try using `.foregroundColor(.primary)` directly on what you want to keep the color.

Comment: @kontiki tried the same but it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one, it works for me, but since I don't have the `SearchUserRow()` code, I cannot fully try it myself:

```swift
SearchUserRow(user: user).foregroundColor(.primary)
    .contentShape(Rectangle())
    .onTapGesture { ... }
```